# Mathjax shifted frames

Tags: support, bug, mathjax

Mathjax frames(hats and arrows) are shifted in Safari 10.1 in MacOS Sierra. However, it was working fine yesterday.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: The [answer in question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/324278/how-do-normalised-plane-wave-solutions-work/324283#324283) looks fine to me, on chrome over windows.

Comment: I know. It happens only in Safari.

Comment: Are you running any extensions that could modify the behaviour? (If you were running chrome I would ask whether the behaviour persists in incognito mode, which turns off extensions by default; I don't know Safari but I imagine it has equivalent functionality.) Additional diagnostics - does the problem also show up on other SE sites such as [math.se]? Does it also happen on http://mathjax.org or other sites that use mathjax?

Comment: I only have a downloader extension installed in both safari and chrome but it is deactivated. It looks fine on chrome on my system as well. I have the same problem with mathematics site but not in mathjax website.

Comment: This is [issue 1709](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1709) on the MathJax tracker.  Apparently there is a change in WebKit in recent Safari that causes this.

Comment: Ok I'll report it as a bug then. But it only happens in SE though.

Comment: It only affects the CommonHTML output, so perhaps you are only using CommonHTML on SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Davide Cervone](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7901/davide-cervone) writes in a comment:

> This is [issue 1709](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/issues/1709) on the MathJax tracker.  Apparently there is a change in WebKit in recent Safari that causes this.